# Flutter url launcher can't send headers on release apk

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

So, i have an app where i can download something from my server using redirecting url with header.

I implement it on flutter like this

```
 _launchURL(String url, String token) async{
    print(url);
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url,headers: {'token': token});
      // await launch(url,headers: {'token': token});
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

It works fine on AVD, i also add logger on my server to saved every request has certain header that i desired, but when i release my project using `flutter build apk --release` and install on my device, but the request download is sent wihtout header.
is there any manifest i need to add so `launch url` can launch url with specific header?

Answer (score 0):

Not all web browsers have support for sending additional headers alongside with the intent as mentioned in this issue [ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61332).

A workaround here is to use a WebView to open the link.

```dart
await launchUrl(url, 
  forceWebView: true,
  webViewConfiguration: WebViewConfiguration(
      headers: <String, String>{'token': token}),)
```